# c# adwords api adgroupid?

Tags: c#, api, google-ads-api

İ want to use adwords api and looking for samples in ;

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/samples/csharp/optimization#get-keyword-ideas

What is `"INSERT_ADGROUP_ID_HERE"` ? How can i fİnd the "ADGROUPID"

İ want form application which has a button,textbox,listbox to get related keywords with keyword that given in the textbox , so please help me about this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass on an adgroup ID (referencing an Adgroup ) on which you need to perform operations that can be any Add,Modify, Delete operation. This is an unique Constant for referencing every adgroup.

You can find it in Adwords UI by selecting new Coulmn

Coulmns > Modify Columns >  Attributes > Ad Group Id

You need to be on Adgroup Level Tab to make this option Visible